# Django ORM : Categorizing a list query on multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

My title may seem vague, but I'm sorry to save I have no other idea on how to phrase this. Assuming my model structure looks like this:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...necessary stuff...)

class Cuisine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...necessary stuff...)
    # thai chinese indian etc.

class Food(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='restaurant')
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, related_name='cuisine')
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

What I want is a list of objects of Food of a specific restaurant. But the Food objects need to be under their respective Cuisine, so that I can easily access the Food through the context. Is it possible to achieve this in any way?

My current query:

```
q = Cuisine.objects.prefetch_related('cuisine')
q = q.filter(cuisine__restaurant_id=restaurant.id) # say restaurant.id=1
# here restaurant is the object which I have retrieved
```

Well, what it does is it filters the cuisines available to the restaurant, but lists all food within those cuisine. I want only the food available in the restaurant. I think I am missing something in the way I built my models, but I'm not certain. It would be really helpful if someone could point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Food.objects.filter(restuarant_id=1, cuisine_id__in=selected_cuisine_ids)
```

Here, `selected_cuisine_ids` is the list of IDs of whichever cuisines needed

Comment: Thanks, adding this query within the prefetch_related(Prefetch(...)) did the trick :D

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) with [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) argument. So your models should be like:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...necessary stuff...)
    cuisines = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant, through='Food', related_name='restaurants')

class Cuisine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...necessary stuff...)
    # thai chinese indian etc. 

class Food(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='restaurant')
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, related_name='cuisine')
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

In this way, your query would be like this:

```
Cuisine.objects.filter(restaurants__id=1)
```

Comment: I already tried this, the problem is I don't just want the Cuisines, I want the Food (which are served by the restaurant) under each Cuisine to be included as well